# How do I figure out what proportion of ferric chloride I use for etching 304 & 316 stainless steel?

Tags: materials, steel, surface-preparation

I am trying to etch a Damascus ring (cold rolled 304 & 316 stainless) however I keep getting pits or a terribly light etch. So far I've tried:

415 chloric ferride with

- 1 to 3 water solution for 20 minutes. Did basically nothing.
- 1 to one water solution for 10 minutes, then wiped with Windex. Pitting started.

I can certainly try different combinations, but I was wondering if there is a better way to figure out how to get a dark etch. Any formulas I can use or something? Is there a rule of thumb?

Comment: one to one solution for 30 seconds, wipe & check. Rinse and repeat until effect required is reached. Of course this is my opinion but seems logical based on your failed attempts described.